# PHP7 driver not found (mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here is my connection code (PHP7):

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql :host='.$host.';dbname='.$database, $user, $password);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('Erreur  : ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

And I receive the following error 'could not find driver" :

My phpinfo():

```
                PDO
PDO support     enabled

PDO drivers     mysql, sqlite

            pdo_mysql
PDO Driver for MySQL        enabled
Client API version      mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: b5c5906d452ec590732a93b051f3827e02749b83 $

Directive                       Local Value                     Master Value
pdo_mysql.default_socket        /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock     /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Any idea?

Comment: This is an English language site. Please ask your question in English.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead this connection string:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $user, $password);
```

Poorly placed spaces will cause problems.